# C# UWP Connect to SharedFolder

Tags: c#, directory, uwp

I can not connect a UWP with a public shared folder another system.

Example:

```
new CredentialCache().Add(new Uri(@"\\[IP]"), 
       "Basic",new NetworkCredential("[USER]", "PASS]", "[IP]"));
```

or

```
new CredentialCache().Add(new Uri(@"\\[IP]"),"Digest",
        new NetworkCredential("[USER]", "[PASS]", "[IP]"));
```

or

```
new CredentialCache().Add(new Uri(@"\\[IP]"), "SHARED", 
        new NetworkCredential("[USER]", "[PASS]", "[IP]"));


var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\[IP]\[SharedName]");
```

or

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\[IP]\[SharedName]");
```

1. Exception: network access danied
2. Exception: Access is danied

Comment: Double check your cradentials? if you're danied it might be that

Comment: already is solved.
In Manifest add:

 <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
          <uap:ShareTarget Description="SharedP">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:SupportsAnyFileType />
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:DataFormat>Text</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>Uri</uap:DataFormat>
          </uap:ShareTarget>
        </uap:Extension>